# when writing C # code in Visual Studio, How do I use shortcut keys to automatically using all unused reference in the current file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When writing Java using vscode, I can use Shift+Alt+O to automatically import all packages. So, what about in visual studio C#?

I've been searching for a long time, but I don't seem to have found a solution, I don't want to scroll the mouse multiple times in a file, just use Ctrl+one by one.

Comment: Do you have the 'Show errors' window open? then you can click on the unreferenced code, where you can add them.

Comment: Unfortunately, it can't be done fully automatically because a symbol with the same name can be declared in different namespaces/packages.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio for C#, you could use the "Organize Usings" feature to automatically sort and remove unnecessary using directives.
The default shortcut for this action is Ctrl + R, Ctrl + G.

Here's how you can use it:
Place the cursor anywhere within the file.
Press Ctrl + R, Ctrl + G.

I created new wpf application to test. Here's my test.

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
      public MainWindow()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
      }
  }
```

Press Ctrl + R, Ctrl + G. Only the reference `using System.Windows;` is left.

When I add the following code, the reference `using System.ComponentModel;` and `using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;` is automatically added.

```
 public class Walk : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
     private int _Id { get; set; }
     public int Id
     {
         get
         {
             return _Id;
         }
         set
         {
             _Id = value;
             OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Id));
         }
     }

     private string _Name;

     public string Name
     {
         get
         {
             return _Name;
         }
         set
         {
             _Name = value;
             OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
         }
     }


     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
     private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "") =>
         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

 }
```